# How can I make Tomboy start a certain note on login?

Tags: 10.04, tomboy

Is it possible to integrate tomboy a bit more during startup? I'm using on a kind of index-note where I always start the program. Maybe it can show up open every time I log in? (See pictures)

I hope there is a plugin or something.

This is the current situation after startup:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

And in my dreams is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate [How do I make a program auto-start everytime I log in?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by executing the command

`tomboy --open-note <Note Title>`

In your example this would be `tomboy --open-note TODO`

How to add this to your startup applications is described here: [How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)