# How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?

Tags: login, autostart

I frequently need to start several programs that I use every time I start my computer. How can I make it so that whenever I login the program is automatically launched?

Comment: I presume `Menu > Preferences > Startup Applications` doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: @Kaustubh - it does. But I like generic questions rather than the same question asked multiple times with slightly different programs :)

Comment: How can this be achieved from command line?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### To make a program start with Ubuntu:

- If you're using **Unity**, search
  for the program `Startup
  Applications`.
- If you're using **Ubuntu Classic**,
  it's under **Start Menu >
  Preferences > Startup Applications**.

---

### To make Ubuntu remember your running applications on shutdown:

1. Open a terminal, and run
   `gconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to
   **/apps/gnome-session/options**.[image]
3. Enable the option:
   **auto_save_session**.

(NOTE: this may slow system boot, and has not been throughly tested.)

Comment: i did that but like i remember in 10.10 it has a button that said click here to remember all applications open to be start up automatically (or something like that)

Comment: Please see my edited post.

Comment: okay..so its being fixed right? or being "discussed"

Comment: That post is from February when Natty was being tested. There is no other information that goes along with it, but I would assume they are still trying to fix it.

Comment: okay ...thank you for informing this information

Comment: Kevin, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/38988/is-there-a-way-for-saving-a-session-in-11-04.

Comment: No joy for me. I set the flag, but the various terminal windows (with multiple tabs) that I created in the various workspaces before I logged off were not restored when I logged back in.

Comment: Yes. The reason this option was removed from its normal spot in Startup Applications, is because it has become "broken" in a way. Although some users still report that it works fine, in your case, it may be the other way around.

Comment: is there something similar for oposite solution when user log-out from unity

Comment: That's not work on Ubuntu 12.04 - there is only `splash_image` item in the options. I've also tried to add `auto-save-session=true` option manually but it didn't help, running applications don't restore after restart...

Answer (score 29):

### User defined sessions for applications to start after login

An alternative way to automatically start applications after login is to define a user defined session. This has the advantage to use different sessions for different task, each with different applications loaded.

For this purpose we create a `custom.desktop` file **as root** in `/usr/share/xsessions` with the following content (for GNOME/GDM):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Marco's Crowded Session
Comment=Custom ~/.xsession script
Exec=/home/username/.xsession
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gdm
```

Use any fancy name for your session and replace `username` by your name of course.

This will run the script `.xsession` in the HOME directory at login where we can put in any appplications we need to start after login.

The script needs to be named as defined in the .desktop file, that is `~/.xsession` in the example given, **needs to be made executable** and may have a content similar to this:

```
#! /bin/bash

my-important-app [options] &
second-app [options] &
[...]                       # add other applications
gnome-session [options]
```

Options for gnome-session may be omitted to load the default session. Give e.g. `--session=classic-gnome` as option to run Classic GNOME Desktop in 11.04.

Next time we login we will have the choice to start a **"Marco's Crowded Session"** with all applications from the script running in addition to applications from the gnome-session (or any other desktop manager you chose to start here).

#### Starting other desktop managers

To start another **installed** desktop manager replace the last line from the `~/.xsession` script with the following:

- `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` for standard desktop (with Unity in 11.04).
- `gnome-session --session=classic-gnome` for classic GNOME desktop.
- `startkde` for KDE desktop manager.
- `startxfce4` for XFCE, or when running Xubuntu.

Comment: I like it *clicks imaginary like button*

Answer (score 16):

### 12.04 (Unity)

We can add applications to the *"Startup Applications"* by opening the menu entry on the top panel right side:

[image]

### 14.04 (Unity) and later

We can search the Dash for "startup applications"

[image]

or we can run the startup preferences from a terminal with

```
gnome-session-properties
```

---

This will open a window where we can see all installed applications that will run on startup. Tick or untick the applications there or choose *"Add"* to add a new application:

[image]

If we know the command to run the application just enter it here in the *"Command"* line. We may also add an optional *"Comment"* here.

If we do not know the command we can choose to *"Browse..."* our file system for installed applications. Many default applications are found e.g. in `/usr/share/application`:

[image]

Select an application to add to autostart.

### Command line or programmatical approach

Similar to what the GUI solution above does we can manually add a `.desktop` file to `~/.config/autostart`. The content of this file may be as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=</path/to/binary or command to execute>
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=<Name_to_be_displayed>
Comment=<optional comment>
```

Note that in a vanilla installation the directory `~/.config/autostart` may not yet exist. We need to create it before we can access it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the programmatic approach, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is this working with Unity desktop or i need Gnome desktop? Cause with Unity in 15.04 its not working.

Comment: @YumYumYum thank you for the notice - updated answer :)

Comment: Is the `~/.config/autostart` portable? The other two look to be supported by the GNOME desktop environment and Unity.

Comment: It is available on all X-systems where we had ot specified a different directory spec. See https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the **[GNOME](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GNOME)** ***[Desktop Environment](http://www.gnome.org/)***, then this is rather simple to accomplish.

- Go to `System>Preferences>Startup Applications`,

[image: menu screenshot]

- Now you can either add an application by clicking add,

[image]

- And adding the application/script you want to run on startup,

[image]

- **Or** you can add an application by dragging the launcher you wish to add from the Application menu to the Startup Applications screen.

Comment: For Gnome Shell, you have to open it though Ctrl + F2 and typing gnome-session-properties

Comment: Can this be done in Unity desktop?

Answer (score 4):

Another, possibly simpler, option would be to go to menu System/Preferences/Startup applications, then choose the "Options" tab and tick "Automatically remember running applications when logging out"

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

This will start up any applications you have running when you log out.

Comment: +1 but this needs to be handled with care. If one of the apps just running is buggy or crashes the X-Server you may end up with a bad to handle no-fun system (I had that once).

Comment: Yeah, I admit - that's why I stopped using it too.  There is always "gnome-failsafe" session, I suppose, but I couldn't figure out how to recover my crashed session.  That was years ago though.  Hard to believe it would happen these days.

Comment: How to get this Options tab in Ubuntu 12.04? there is only one `Startup Programs` one

Comment: 12.04 has removed the "automatically remember" option I show above. You have to search Dash for "Startup Applications" then manually add the entries you want.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers (until now) gives a **user-independent solution**.

The correct way (according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8290652/1461017)) to add some autorunning program (named a Desktop Entry) **for the whole Operating System** is adding it as a `.desktop` file here:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
```

Example of `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyScript
GenericName=A descriptive name
Comment=Some description about your script
Exec=/path/to/my/script.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

No need to `chmod` it to executable permission, it seems.
The `Exec` will run for any logging user, including `root`, `ubuntu` or `xubuntu` (for custom Live distribution desktops)

Answer (score 1):

In 11.04, you press the powerbutton (rightmost on the upper panel) and select System settings. You'll find Startup Applications under Personal preferences. It's the same dialog that we had in earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that you can add the command in System --> Preferences --> app Start

then click add, put a name somthing like "Firefox start" the command name part click

"examine" and look for executable file of the program that you need start at login...restart

hope this help you!!!

regards!!!