# How to check if a given PPA or repository is available

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I am working on generating some auto install scripts that would work on different versions of Ubuntu. Therefore, I try to keep the `add-apt-repository` statements generic as seen below.

```
add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:graphics-drivers
```

However, as some repos don't exist for certain versions, auto generated **url**s might lead to errors like below.

```
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu disco Release
    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, an is therefore disabled by default.
```

I know that this can't be kept 100% flexible across all versions without keeping `ubuntu version vs package repo` lookup tables/if-else statements. However, for my simple purposes, it is enough to know if any given url/ppa is valid or not.

So, is there a way to test this without adding the url/ppa and seeing it to fail on next `apt update`?

**Update:**

As pointed out, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365902/how-can-i-check-if-a-ppa-has-packages-for-another-ubuntu-version) is closely related to mine but my aim is to check the validity before adding to the sources list, also, both for **PPA**s and **repo url**s. So, I've come up with the scripts below which possibly can be improved but also seem to do the job.

```
function add_ppa() {
  local __ppa_name
  for __ppa_name in "$@"; do
    grep -h "^deb.*$__ppa_name" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" != "0" ]
    then
        local __ppa_prefix=$(echo $__ppa_name | cut -d"/" -f1)
        local __ppa_suffix=${__ppa_name##*/}
        curl -fsSL https://launchpad.net/~"$__ppa_prefix"/+archive/ubuntu/"$__ppa_suffix" &>/dev/stdout | grep "\"`lsb_release -sc`\"" -m1 >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then 
            echo "Adding ppa:$__ppa_name"
            sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:$__ppa_name
        fi
    fi
  done
}

function add_to_sources_list() {
    local __repo_base_link="$1"
    local __flavour="$2"
    local __version_name=`lsb_release -sc`
    local __repo_link="deb $__repo_base_link $__version_name $__flavour"

    grep -h "^$__repo_link" /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" != "0" ]
    then
        echo "Adding $__repo_link"
        curl -fsSL "${__repo_base_link}/dists/${__version_name}/Release" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then 
            echo "Adding repo:$__repo_link"
            sudo add-apt-repository -y "$__repo_link"
        fi      
    fi
}

# example use
add_ppa "wireshark-dev/stable"
add_to_sources_list "http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/" "multiverse"
```

Comment: karel and @pilot6 Thanks very much for pointing out, by combining the pointers you provided, I've come up with the functions above.

Comment: If you post your script as an answer to [How can I check if a PPA has packages for another Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365902) I'll upvote it. I like using scripts like this which is why I also upvoted [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161181/).

Comment: Thanks, extended the scripts to satisfy OP's use case too. I've also committed the changes to the mentioned repo as explained in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can alsways check it on PPA Web page.

E.g for `wireshark-dev` PPA you can check

https://launchpad.net/~wireshark-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable

There you can see what is available. You can also filter by Ubuntu release.

As you can see, there is nothing for `disco` if you click "Published in" drop down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I've factored in your hint in scripts for automation. Please see my updated question and response to @karel.