# How to add programs to start up?

Tags: 11.04, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a program auto-start everytime I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

I want to know because I am tired of just clicking on the launcher because I just leave my laptop on. Also it was so easy on 10.10. So I wonder why its so hard on 11.04. Please help me. Thank You