# Is there a way to save a session?

Tags: 11.04, session

Is there a way for saving a session in 11.04 ?

Comment: Do you mean remembering your running applications?

Comment: Yes, Roland. That is exactly what I would like to have in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: try my suggestion below.

Comment: If anyone wants to re-implement this feature (from scratch), the following information may be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/113850/how-to-get-a-list-of-currently-open-files-application-instances-in-unity-launc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save Unity Desktop Session](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78207/save-unity-desktop-session)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this feature was dropped: http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-desktop/478109-gnome-session-saving-dropped-natty.html

There is a bug filed for this (so, someone might be willing at some point to restore the feature): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/773688

But from my own experience, the feature was completely unpredictable: even the File Manager windows were not always restored and those restored were at different spaces/positions etc.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is still available in the configuration editor. (Open dash, type `gconf-editor` and it should show up).

Now, you need to navigate to `/apps/gnome-session/options`.

> [image]

When you autosave your session, you do not have to do anything afterwords (like loading a session file in nautilus). It will automatically save the programs you have running as startup applications.

Comment: I read from a post in February that they had removed this feature because it was broken, does this in fact still work? If so I will add this to an answer I made a few days ago.

Comment: @Alan: I have not tested it myself, but others have said it was working. I think it slows down login time though, and it's a bit complicated to undo (so it is still technically "broken").

Comment: The command to run is actually `gconf-editor`. I edited the answer to say so, but it is pending approval.

Comment: @JoshGlover: Yes, the command is gconf-editor, but the Desktop File is "Configuration Editor".

Comment: @Roland: sure, but opening a terminal and typing `config` didn't work for me. :)

Comment: @JoshGlover: I never mentioned opening a terminal...

Comment: @ Roland: Thanks for the post! I followed it but I don't find there is any session item on Nautilus menu. I am using 10.10.

Comment: @Tim what? Nautilus menu?

Comment: @Roland: auto-save-session has been checked. But I don't know where to choose the saved session, because in Nautilus, there is no related item in its menu.

Comment: @Tim ????????????