# Remember what directories are open in one session of Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I was wondering if it is possible to remember what directories are open in one session of Nautilus, so that next time starting Nautilus, I can reopen the directories. Bookmark opened directories one by one is not what I ask for. Thanks and regards!

Comment: Am using tabs in nautilus; ideally, there'd be a way to dump the locations and have a script to re-open those locations in tabs when needed. I might try and think about how to do this eventually, but if anyone can "get the show on the road" sooner, I'd be v glad!!

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus does not support this functionality. What you might want to do is [use session saving](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38988/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-session/39006#39006), or write a script to have nautilus open those directories by default.

You could replace nautilus with this script in your start up applications. (I will need more time for the script part).

Comment: @Tim is...? You mean how to write the script or to save your session? (BTW I will update my answer shortly).

Comment: @RolandiXor How shortly is 'shortly' :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to try this out myself, but this looks promising: "hot off the press" here's a relatively recent find:

> So I did a little tweaking of the command and came up with this:
>
> **`nautilus --sm-client-state-file ~/.config/session-state/nautilus-xxxxxxxxxx.desktop &`**
>
> And it worked beautifully!
>
> *Last edited by **[tg3793](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042877&pp=150)**; June 9th, **2012** at 08:37 AM.*

Let's hope it works!