# How could Unity2D save sessions?

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d

Until 11.10 I used Kubuntu. For some annoying reasons i migrated to Ubuntu from 12.04. Now i really miss some KDE features and i don't have found solution yet.

First big problem: i work with lot of windows ( >20 ) and i set them on different workplaces. I avoid restarting computer, but sometimes it is neccessary. And then is so tedious to set my workspace up again. Is there some cure for that?

I read already some sources:
    [Save Unity Desktop Session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78207/save-unity-desktop-session) and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/771896 and https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-January/002734.html.

Is there some change in 12.04? What is the meaning of workplaces, when you need to set them up every time after login?

Comment: The general idea is that suspend and hibernate are the way to go. When those work they work well.

Comment: @Rinzwind: AFAIU there is no hibernate in 12.04 by default. It is not rare to my laptop to have uptime more than month, but still there are cases when i need restart computer. For example, last week i tried to add printer and computer hanged totally. No access to console neither through SSH, only way was reboot. And it is tedious to build your workplaces up from scratch every time.

Answer (score 9):

**Info**
The feature to save session has been [removed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11753547&postcount=17) in Ubuntu 12.04 because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/773688).

**First**
I have made a workaround that is a script that helps to configure your session. Just paste the command below at terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This if you are using Metacity (Unity-2d):

```
cd ~/ && wget -c http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/session.meta.config && chmod +x ~/session.meta.config && ~/session.meta.config
```

.

Or this if you are using Compiz (Unity-3d):

```
cd ~/ && wget -c http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/session.config && chmod +x ~/session.config && ~/session.config
```

You can view the code of script ([1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/session.config), [2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/session.meta.config)). There are explanations in each part. It will create a startup script which will move to each viewport (or desktop) and open the specified application.

*Removing*

To remove any changes made by my script just delete this files (if they exists):

- ~/session.config
- ~/session.meta.config
- ~/sessionconf
- ~/sessionconf.bak
- ~/.config/autostart/sessionconf.desktop

Or run this at terminal:

```
rm ~/session.config ; rm ~/session.meta.config ; rm ~/sessionconf ; rm ~/sessionconf.bak ; rm ~/.config/autostart/sessionconf.desktop
```

---

**Second**
There are others workarounds like [TuxOnIce](http://tuxonice.net/):

"TuxOnIce is most easily described as the Linux equivalent of Windows' hibernate functionality, but better. It saves the contents of memory to disk and powers down. When the computer is started up again, it reloads the contents and the user can continue from where they left off. No documents need to be reloaded or applications reopened and the process is much faster than a normal shutdown and start up."

See it working [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_T4ZcPkqVA&feature=player_embedded).

You can install it through "tuxonice/ppa":
1) Add the ppa: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa`
2) Update: `sudo apt-get update`
3) Install `sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice`

---

**Third**
A third idea is to set Compiz to launch windows in selected viewports:

1) Install [CompizConfig-Settings-Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager),

2) Open <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

3) Go to "Place Windows"

[image]

4) Select "Fixed Window Placement" > "Window with fixed viewport" > "New"

[image]

5) Select the window by class, id, title, name, type or role and set the viewport it should be placed:

[image]

[image]

6) Now add your apps to "Startup Applications" (press <kbd>Super</kbd> and type `Startup Applications`)

Comment: Your First idea has something in it. If i got nothing else, this is the way to go. Thank you for your efforts! As i use Unity-2d i avoid Compiz too.

Comment: I thought you were using Compiz,  I will re write to work in metacity.

Comment: Got it working with metacity! I'm happy :-)

Comment: Does it work with a lot of windows of one app? I mean, most of my windows are Chromium tab-sets. How could i choose, which are on which workplace?

Comment: I will ask a workspace and you choose (example: "2" for the second workspace) and then I will ask which app and you choose for example "chromium-browser http://askubuntu.com"

Comment: AFAIU your example opens a site askubuntu.com but i need to open my last used set (> 20) of browser windows (with total amount of tabs > 150) properly installed on several workspaces. Have you ideas for that too?

Comment: For each workspace, when I ask for the app, you choose something like "chromium-browser --new-window www.google.com www.uol.com.br www.hotmail.com"

Comment: Yes, but this does not help, because i have X tabs in Y Windows placed on Z workplaces and those X tabs are not fixed URLs but changing dynamically (not all, but that is not important). When i log out and log in again, Chromium restores windows with tabs but not how they were placed on workplaces.

Comment: You are right. This is a limitation of a solution with fixed configuration.

Comment: ** Wellcome ** :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround? (Enable Hibernate)

sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit/localauthority=50-loc.d/hibernate.pkla

And add the following and save:

[Re-enable Hibernate]

Identity=unix-user:*

Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate

ResultActive=yes

NOTE: USE WITH CAUTION! Hibernate was removed for a reason - you can test if this will work before editing hibernate.pkla by trying this in a terminal with some other windows running at the time.

pm-hibernate

Comment: I can't rely on hibernate (i need something working on computer hangs/restarts too) and on my computer hibernate does not work correctly.