# How to save terminal configurations?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I open several terminal to use vim to edit several files.

When I reboot, I should open again so many terminal and files.

How to save the whole state of terminal?

Thank you~

Comment: you can save the session! which ubuntu version did you use?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/129885/how-could-unity2d-save-sessions

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. Thank you for that thread,but its too hard for me to understand. Is there any step by step instructions on ubuntu 12.04 64 bits system to follow? ( I want to know how to save and how to load)

Answer (score 0):

:) ok than you can try this one. you do it with the gconf-editor. 2nd answer with 21 vote ups: [How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

Comment: This will not work:  We now use Unity and dconf-editor for most settings; gconf-editor is for Gnome and partly still for Unity. But the `save session` option has been remove from Ubuntu 11.10 (or even 11.04?) and onwards. Next to that: iirc the `save session` did NOT save terminal windows and their content. Just that the terminal window was open.