# How to save desktop session with Unity?

Tags: unity, session

Is there a **native way** provided by Unity to **save an arbitrary desktop session**, in order to **restore it during next system start**? By desktop session, I refer to all the applications currently running with their windows states regarding work spaces and such.

To make things clear, I do not want to just use any hibernate modes to switch off the computer. Nor do I want to add applications to the Autostart configuration, as this does not solve the issue of having your latest session restored.

While doing research, I found quite a few similiar questions, just like [Save Unity Desktop Session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78207/save-unity-desktop-session) . However, those threads are rather old or have no real solution provided. My concern is Ubuntu 14.04. default installation (thus, using Unity as a window manager). Your help is much appreciated.

Best regards
Ron

Comment: @Pandya The OP explicitly states he doesn't want to hibernate.

Comment: Sometimes it may help, to think things through from the other end. Is somebody out there, who can officially confirm, that there is no such thing like a desktop session safe feature in Ubuntu Unity?