# dconf editor "auto-save-session" not working? 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, session, dconf

so I'm quite new and just started using ubuntu, and I've heard about ubuntu being able to remember all my last windows (enabling "auto-save-session" via dconf editor). And no matter how many times I try to enable it, it never works for me, I don't even get an error message. How can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this feature is not supported in 14.04, seems to be a bug, but there are a few possibilities to work around that function.

1. Using a script

desgua wrote a script where you can configure your session manually which worked for me for each workspace by typing the following into your console:

```
cd ~/ && wget -c http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/session.config && chmod +x ~/session.config && ~/session.config
```

2. Gnome-session-save

Another possibility is to do: `killall gnome-session` then `sudo gnome-session-save --logout` which should save the current session and log out at the same time. It seemed to work for others but not for me.

More details in the posting:
[Save Unity Desktop Session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78207/save-unity-desktop-session)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way folks!

1. Install Compiz Settings Manager if you don't have it already

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Under Categories click on *Utility* and tick the little box next to *Enable Session Management* to activate it.

That's it!!

easy peasy lemon squeezy ;)

Comment: is this work in 15?

Comment: It's already on.. so must not be working :/