# How to remap a key combination to a single key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu on a Samsung Chromebook. As some of you may know, the keyboard used in ChromeOS based netbooks is a bit awkward: amongst other things, it doesn't have a <kbd>Del</kbd> key*. If I were going to use this netbook to its original purpose, browsing, I guess it wouldn't be a problem, but I need to program with it, and I miss a lot of keys, specially the <kbd>Delete</kbd> one, but also <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

So I've been looking for a way to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> arrow to <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, and so on...

I have found a lot of explanations on how to remap one key, but I don't know how I can remap a key combination to a single key. Has anyone tried to do something like this?

Thanks a lot.

*I mean, the key that deletes a character to the right. We call it "Supr" in Spain, I am not sure how it's in english-speaking countries.

Comment: Backspace is the key that deletes a character to the right here, so that's probably what you mean. ;)

Comment: Backspace deletes the character to the left of the cursor, not to the right...

Comment: Backspace deletes a character to the left, Delete deletes a character to the right. And yes, "Supr" is short for "Suprimir", which means "Delete".

Answer (score 11):

You can use `xbindkeys` to grab the keys and `xvkbd` to send keys.

Create a file `.xbindkeysrc` in your home directory and paste this text:

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Delete]'"
  Alt + BackSpace

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Home]'"
  Alt + Left

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Page_Down]'"
  Alt + Down
```

Then start `xbindkeys` and it should work. Probably you want to map more keys, then after you edited the `.xbindkeysrc` you can run `pkill -HUP xbindkeys` to send a HUP signal to xbindkeys (or kill xbindkeys and start it again).

To see the key names that xbindkeys sees, you can run `xbindkeys -mk` (`man xbindkeys` has more info).

To see the key names that xvkbd knows, have a look in /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h (maybe someone else knows a better method?).

xbindkeys only runs until your X session ends, so you probably want to put it in your [startup (auto-start) programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in).

Comment: This kind of works, but the window loses and regains focus every time it sends an event. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No keys are sent.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.04 running X11