# Chromebook Ubuntu Delete Key

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, 16.04, chromebook

Hi wondering how to go about this, I have a Chromebook with Xubuntu installed on it. This Chromebook has no Delete key however it'd be really useful to have now and I'm unsure about how to gain the functionality of having a Delete key or go about mapping a set of keys to a Delete command if there is one? CHeers,

Comment: Got it, apologies https://askubuntu.com/questions/85850/how-to-rombination-to-a-single-key

Answer (score 0):

There is no delete key on a Chromebook, but you can achieve it by holding down the alt key while pressing backspace.