# Remap LWIN + ; to ä

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am using a US keyboard layout, but I need German Umlaute as well. Under windows it was easy to map LWIN + ; to produce an ä, LWIN + ' to an ö.

I read about xbindkeys, xmodmap, ... but everywhere I just don't seem to get the combination right.

How would I do that in Linux/Ubuntu? Thank you so much for your help, it is the last thing keeping me from switching full time to Linux.

Comment: In current Ubuntu versions using Xorg, `xkb` (X keyboard extension) is used to configure key maps. It is, however, rather complicated. `xbindkeys`, while not primarily made for that purpose, is a bit easier to setup and you can't mess up your keyboard configuration with it. I would try `xbindkeys` first; if the result is not satisfactory, try `xkb`.

Comment: Thank you @danzel for helping! I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/85850/how-to-remap-a-key-combination-to-a-single-key but it does not seem to work. Does that maybe have something to do with LWIN trying to open "search"?

Comment: I need to switch back to German every once in a while on a US keyboard. My method is rather low-tech. I have both layouts installed and switch using the language drop-down. Most of the keys in the German layout are the same anyway except for Z. If I feel I need to switch back and forth too often because I can't find the key I am looking for I make sure I have one of each umlaut in the text and the esszett and then I switch back to US layout and copy from the existing characters when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Define a compose key.

[How to set a Compose Key in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028957/how-to-set-a-compose-key-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Once done, you can do for instance:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by " followed by a => ä

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by " followed by o => ö

Comment: I also think it's the best option, using a "useless" key like Scroll Lock as a compose key is incredibly powerful, and also makes using foreign keyboards a pleasure!

Comment: Note only "Right Super" compose key can be setup but OP specifically wants to use "Left Super" as compose key...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Actually XKB understands `compose:lwin` too, but apparently you can't choose that option from _Tweaks_. OTOH, using a compose key is not exactly as the OP described the Windows feature anyway, so in any case I think the OP needs to get used to a slightly different method to achieve the goal.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I concur. Just pointing out differences.