# Alternative to xbindkeys that allows key-combos sans modifier keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xorg, keyboard-layout

When I press `XF86TouchpadOn` + `Left` I want it to mimic `Home` button pressed.

I tried [xbindkeys](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xbindkeys_tutorial.html), [with xvkbd](https://superuser.com/questions/469004/) and [with xdotool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85850/) but none worked.

Here's my `.xbindkeysrc`

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Next]'"
  XF86TouchpadOn + 2

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Prior]'"
  XF86TouchpadOn + 8

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Home]'"
  XF86TouchpadOn + 4

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[End]'"
  XF86TouchpadOn + 6
```

Note Left Right etc. are swapped by 4 6 etc. because once xbindkeys is running - arrow keys don't work (neither singularly nor in XF86TouchpadOn-combo; they get completely blocked) and that prevents me from using the terminal easily.

So, what are alternatives to xbindkeys that allows me mimic a keypress when a key-combination, *that does not have modifier-key in it*, is pressed.

---

Alternatively, is there a way to make keys behave conditionally? E.g. when CapsLk is on, letter remain small but arrow keys become page navigation keys?

Comment: You may want to take a look at `sxhkd`, which allows to define multiple chords (i.e., press a few keys sequentially to trigger a command).

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper could help.