# How to launch Thunderbird when Ubuntu 11.10 starts?

Tags: thunderbird, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a program auto-start everytime I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

I would like to configure Thunderbird to starts when the session starts, but I don't know how!
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This question was already posted here in AskUbuntu:

[How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

Here is another link from the Ubuntu official guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the answer is to add the command line to the System launcher at boot (System->Preferences->Applications at Startup). The command to launch Thunderbird from command line is: /usr/bin/thunderbird. With this, I have solved my issue!