# Empathy Sign-In automatically

Tags: empathy, auto-login

When I start my machine the empathy starts unavailable until I press on the chat Icon at the upper right edge of the screen and set it as available

How can empathy start automatically after user logon?

Answer (score 2):

I've added `empathy -h` to my [Startup Aplications](https://askubuntu.com/q/30931/65926) and it works in my case. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi, I have the very same issue in 13.04 final, no auto start on logon, need to click chat Icon at the upper right edge of the screen