# how to make a program autostart at every login on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, autostart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a program auto-start everytime I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

How make a program autostart et every login.

I see this link but not for 12.10 [How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would depend on what desktop environment you're running.  Here is how to manage startup applications if you are using:

[Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically) (the default)
[Gnome-Shell](http://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/manage-the-startup-applications/)
[KDE](http://itg.chem.indiana.edu/inc/wiki/software/168.html)
MATE is the same as Gnome-Shell.