# Xresources not working properly after restart

Tags: command-line, fonts

I am trying to change my xterm theme using a hack in Xresources which i found in this [website](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Configure_xterm_Fonts_and_Colors_for_Your_Eyeball). i have created a Xresources in my home dirctory and entered the below code.

```
XTerm*faceName: Bitstream Vera Serif Mono
xterm*faceSize: 11
xterm*vt100*geometry: 80x60
xterm*saveLines: 16384
xterm*loginShell: true
xterm*charClass: 33:48,35:48,37:48,43:48,45-47:48,64:48,95:48,126:48
xterm*termName: xterm-color
xterm*eightBitInput: false

!BLK Cursor
#define _color0        #000d18
#define _color8        #000d18
!RED Tag
#define _color1        #e89393
#define _color9        #e89393
!GRN SpecialKey
#define _color2        #9ece9e
#define _color10       #9ece9e
!YEL Keyword
#define _color3        #f0dfaf
#define _color11       #f0dfaf
!BLU Number
#define _color4        #8cd0d3
#define _color12       #8cd0d3
!MAG Precondit
#define _color5        #c0bed1
#define _color13       #c0bed1
!CYN Float
#define _color6        #dfaf8f
#define _color14       #dfaf8f
!WHT Search
#define _color7        #efefef
#define _color15       #efefef
!FMT Include, StatusLine, ErrorMsg
#define _colorBD       #ffcfaf
#define _colorUL       #ccdc90
#define _colorIT       #80d4aa
!TXT Normal, Normal, Cursor
#define _foreground    #dcdccc
#define _background    #1f1f1f
#define _cursorColor   #8faf9f
URxvt*color0         : _color0
URxvt*color1         : _color1
URxvt*color2         : _color2
URxvt*color3         : _color3
URxvt*color4         : _color4
URxvt*color5         : _color5
URxvt*color6         : _color6
URxvt*color7         : _color7
URxvt*color8         : _color8
URxvt*color9         : _color9
URxvt*color10        : _color10
URxvt*color11        : _color11
URxvt*color12        : _color12
URxvt*color13        : _color13
URxvt*color14        : _color14
URxvt*color15        : _color15
URxvt*colorBD        : _colorBD
URxvt*colorIT        : _colorIT
URxvt*colorUL        : _colorUL
URxvt*foreground     : _foreground
URxvt*background     : _background
URxvt*cursorColor    : _cursorColor
XTerm*color0         : _color0
XTerm*color1         : _color1
XTerm*color2         : _color2
XTerm*color3         : _color3
XTerm*color4         : _color4
XTerm*color5         : _color5
XTerm*color6         : _color6
XTerm*color7         : _color7
XTerm*color8         : _color8
XTerm*color9         : _color9
XTerm*color10        : _color10
XTerm*color11        : _color11
XTerm*color12        : _color12
XTerm*color13        : _color13
XTerm*color14        : _color14
XTerm*color15        : _color15
XTerm*colorBD        : _colorBD
XTerm*colorIT        : _colorIT
XTerm*colorUL        : _colorUL
XTerm*foreground     : _foreground
XTerm*background     : _background
XTerm*cursorColor    : _cursorColor
```

to merge i used this code

```
 xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

This worked and my xterm font and background size and color changed

[image]

But the problem starts when i restart my system. After restart when i open my Xterm i get below result with change in background and font color (with out any change in dimension or font size)

[image]

To load again Xresources file i have to use this command everytime when i restart the system.

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

can  you tell what is happening in the above scripts which prevents the smooth execution of Xresources

Answer (score 2):

I think that the name of this file should be a different one (at least on Ubuntu). 
Try(1) the following:

1. find your `hostname`:

   ```
   % hostname
   pern
   ```

   (type `hostname` in your preferred shell --- in the same xterm if you like. You'll have the hostname printed --- in my case it is "pern").
2. you should use `.Xdefaults-hostname` as a file name for your default resource file. For example, supposing your is .Xresource, you can create a symbolic link:

   ```
   cd ~; ln -s .Xresources .Xdefaults-$(hostname)
   ```

   (more simply put: the resources file should be called after your hostname; so if for example your hostname is `alfabeta`, your resource file should be named `.Xdefaults-alfabeta`. The above command, typed as is in a shell, will take care of creating an alias, aka symbolic link, for your existing `.Xresources` file(2))

...and now it should load it at startup (logout and login to check, no need to reboot).

As a last resort, you can try to put the `xrdb` command in an executable script named `.xprofile` (works for me in Xubuntu) or `.xsessionrc` in your home directory, or add it to your [session startup programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in).

---

*Footnotes*:

(1) all the X11 resource mechanism, although not officialy obsoleted, is basically used only by programs from the 90ies and before (`XJed`, `xterm`, `xfig` and so on). Which I still use, together with a couple more dinosaurs. Probably the status of the maintenance of the scripts loading them is, well, lagging. Given that you are a new user, why not going with a more powerful terminal emulator like, for example, `terminator`? It has profiles, configurability, split screen, status line, and a lot fancier stuff than ole good `xterm`.

(2) that, by the way, I do not know why it is not working. It should be loaded by `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources`, which is sourced by `/etc/X11/Xsession`. Anyone?

Comment: I am an average joe, can you explain it a little bit simpler.. how to find host name? `[romano:~/etc] % hostname pern` where to put this code?

Comment: still its not working `cd ~; ln -s .Xresources .Xdefaults-$(hostname) ` created a hidden file in my home directory `.Xdefaults-oc` when i opened this file i can see the xterm theme codes

Comment: is there a way to go back to my previous state, after performing the modifications mentioned in your answer i am not even able to load xresources using `xrdb ~/.Xresources`

Comment: Simply remove the link - the new file `.Xdefaults-oc`. Shouldn't have affected in any way tough. What is the error from `xrdb`?

Comment: `xrdb` shows no error but i am unable to change the theme from white background to black as i previously did using `xrdb ~/.Xresources`

Comment: As you told i have deleted `.Xdefaults-oc` and able to go back to my previous state but still my initial problem exists