# Unable to login after playing with rc.local file

Tags: login, system, crash

I was trying to run a terminal command on startup in my ubuntu 14.04.02

> xrdb ~/.Xresources

I found this method in [super user](https://superuser.com/a/471256) in which `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file is edited. As mentioned in that post I added my code to top of  `rc.local` file using root privilages and saved it.

like this

```
# Resource file load
xrdb ~/.Xresources
#End
```

but after restarting I am unable to "properly" login to the system. After login into the system I can only see  a `home folder` and a `trash folder` in my desktop. No panel, launcer bar noting when i tried to open home folder I am able to reach home folder but after that navigation is not possible (including search)  system hangs. Any idea how to solve this problem

xresources file

```
XTerm*faceName: Bitstream Vera Serif Mono
xterm*faceSize: 11
xterm*vt100*geometry: 80x60
xterm*saveLines: 16384
xterm*loginShell: true
xterm*charClass: 33:48,35:48,37:48,43:48,45-47:48,64:48,95:48,126:48
xterm*termName: xterm-color
xterm*eightBitInput: false

!BLK Cursor
#define _color0        #000d18
#define _color8        #000d18
!RED Tag
#define _color1        #e89393
#define _color9        #e89393
!GRN SpecialKey
#define _color2        #9ece9e
#define _color10       #9ece9e
!YEL Keyword
#define _color3        #f0dfaf
#define _color11       #f0dfaf
!BLU Number
#define _color4        #8cd0d3
#define _color12       #8cd0d3
!MAG Precondit
#define _color5        #c0bed1
#define _color13       #c0bed1
!CYN Float
#define _color6        #dfaf8f
#define _color14       #dfaf8f
!WHT Search
#define _color7        #efefef
#define _color15       #efefef
!FMT Include, StatusLine, ErrorMsg
#define _colorBD       #ffcfaf
#define _colorUL       #ccdc90
#define _colorIT       #80d4aa
!TXT Normal, Normal, Cursor
#define _foreground    #dcdccc
#define _background    #1f1f1f
#define _cursorColor   #8faf9f
URxvt*color0         : _color0
URxvt*color1         : _color1
URxvt*color2         : _color2
URxvt*color3         : _color3
URxvt*color4         : _color4
URxvt*color5         : _color5
URxvt*color6         : _color6
URxvt*color7         : _color7
URxvt*color8         : _color8
URxvt*color9         : _color9
URxvt*color10        : _color10
URxvt*color11        : _color11
URxvt*color12        : _color12
URxvt*color13        : _color13
URxvt*color14        : _color14
URxvt*color15        : _color15
URxvt*colorBD        : _colorBD
URxvt*colorIT        : _colorIT
URxvt*colorUL        : _colorUL
URxvt*foreground     : _foreground
URxvt*background     : _background
URxvt*cursorColor    : _cursorColor
XTerm*color0         : _color0
XTerm*color1         : _color1
XTerm*color2         : _color2
XTerm*color3         : _color3
XTerm*color4         : _color4
XTerm*color5         : _color5
XTerm*color6         : _color6
XTerm*color7         : _color7
XTerm*color8         : _color8
XTerm*color9         : _color9
XTerm*color10        : _color10
XTerm*color11        : _color11
XTerm*color12        : _color12
XTerm*color13        : _color13
XTerm*color14        : _color14
XTerm*color15        : _color15
XTerm*colorBD        : _colorBD
XTerm*colorIT        : _colorIT
XTerm*colorUL        : _colorUL
XTerm*foreground     : _foreground
XTerm*background     : _background
XTerm*cursorColor    : _cursorColor
```

rc.local file(`/etc/init.d/rc.local`)

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start() {
    if [ -x /etc/rc.local ]; then
            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_begin_msg "Running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local)"
        /etc/rc.local
        ES=$?
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $ES
        return $ES
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    do_start
        ;;
    restart|reload|force-reload)
        echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
    stop)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

rcfile (`/etc/rc.local`)

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

Comment: @PKumar Why `/tmp`?

Comment: @A.B. sorry my mistake

Comment: Show the content of `~/.Xresources`

Comment: the content of your `~/.Xresources` works great, and also `xrdb ~/.Xresources`. That can't be the problem.

Comment: @A.B. sorry i edited rc.local file here `/etc/init.d/rc.local`

Comment: I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: @A.B. if it helps I have added my current `rc.local` file details

Comment: I think you have something entered in the file `/etc/init.d/rc.local`?

Comment: the rc.local file details have been uploaded to the question itself and i am unable to find where i made the mistake.. May be some how i corrupted my system

Comment: Have you undone your changes? Did you edit `/etc/init.d/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: I put code inside  `/etc/init.d/rc.local ` instead of `/etc/rc.local` but i also removed the problematic code  from `/etc/init.d/rc.local ` but still my system doesnt show panel or  lanucher

Comment: `sudo service rc.local restart` and `sudo service lightdm restart` This is in my answer.

Comment: And if that does not help, then reboot exceptionally your box.

Comment: executed `sudo service rc.local restart` and it shows this error `Error: argument 'restart' not supported`. whether copying an etc folder from different Ubuntu system to my ubuntu will solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/471256) says: `/etc/rc.local` and not `/etc/init.d/rc.local`

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for a terminal. Log in and open `/etc/init.d/rc.local`:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

**Remove this:**

```
# Resource file load
xrdb ~/.Xresources
#End
```

And besides, the line `xrdb ~/.Xresources` does no not make any sense.

After that:

```
sudo service rc.local restart
sudo service lightdm restart
```

*Or in other words: Use TTY1 to correct your changes.*

Comment: I tried removing the added code but after restarting the problem still exists.`sudo service lightdm restart` this i have to try

Comment: @Eka Then please describe what you've been changed.

Comment: I have trouble loading my Xresources file and i have asked a question regarding that in this [SE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/609459/xresources-not-working-properly-after-restart) but i am unable to solve the loading problem. what i have done sofar is after a fresh restart i have to load xresources file manually from terminal `xrdb ~/.Xresources`. Because this is a simple terminal command I thought to add this terminal command on startup and found rc.local method. Do ubuntu have system recovery option like in windows?