# How to turn off my graphic card led Logo (Gigabyte Nvidia GTX970)

Tags: nvidia

On windows its possible to turn it off with [geforce-experience](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience) and it seems that it doesn't do it definitly, it does it by software on the driver... 
[image]

Comment: same problem, same solution on GTX 1060

Comment: The solution provided here sadly does not apply to the GTX 1080.

Answer (score 11):

```
nvidia-settings --assign GPULogoBrightness=0
```

**All attributes** can be found by `nvidia-settings -q all`

Refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in) for starting it at **boot**

The solution I choosed is to put in my `~/.xinitrc` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633594/run-shell-script-after-xserver-is-started) you can do it by the following command `echo "nvidia-settings --assign GPULogoBrightness=0" >> ~/.xinitrc` if you want it systemwide put it into your `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`

Comment: Any idea how to have it persist after reboot?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc I'd recommend just adding it to startup.

Comment: Put it in a script. Script works when called interactively, but when I put it into init.d and launch it with service then I get "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused"

Comment: @Nobody see the enhanced post... of course if your window manager is not launched you wont be able to run a command which requires an X server

Comment: Didn't work for me: MSI 1080ti, Ubuntu 18.04.