# Turn off LED logo on graphics card (AMD)

Tags: 16.04, radeon, settings, amd-graphics

[A similar question has been asked here before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725459/how-to-turn-off-my-graphic-card-led-logo-gigabyte-nvidia-gtx970), but the solution is specific to NVIDIA.

I believe that on Windows, this is possible to do through a GUI settings application. I have tried `radeontool light off` but that controls something else.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 and the graphics card is a Gigabyte Windforce AMD R9 380x.

Picture of LED in question:

[image: Picture of LED in question]

Comment: I wouldn't think this possible in 16.04, since AMD no longer has proprietary drivers. It may be possible with something manual, but I wouldn't know, and a quick search didn't find anything. You can try 14.04 with proprietary drivers, but there's no guarantee. Have you thought about just putting electrical tape over the light or something (should be fine as long as the cutout isn't also a vent)?