# Algorithm to change ubuntu desktop wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

So, I know there is already some programs over the internet that does this trick. But I imagine that this must be a very simple program to make.

Can I make it with **C** and/or **shell script**? 
I want to make a function that does something like `bool setDesktopBG(ImagePath path)` what are the main calls I must make in order to do it? Which packets should I access to do it? I never coded nothing related to the OS like this so I don't know where exactly to begin?

Also, is this question more suitable to Stack Overflow? If it's the case, I'll delete it and post there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fairly easy question. It uses gsettings. I actually have a shell function in use already. What's your goal specifically ? Just to change wallpaper through code ?

Comment: Yes, then I'll make some kind of `cron` to call it periodically

Comment: I'll be posting answer soon anyway, buy i really would like to know your specific goals here. This question is probably a duplicate, so unless you make it specific, it will be closed. That's my opinion though

Comment: Well, I want to make a program, in this case in shell as you suggested and then I want to set the OS to call it periodically like `sh/bash changeDesktop pathOfFile`

Comment: OK. Working on an answer. `cron` probably isn't the easiest method, but i will throw some other suggestions there.

Comment: Can you please add the specific requirements you've mentioned in the comments to your question ? It's easier for people to see that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What changes the wallpaper**

In case of  Ubuntu's default behavior when it comes to backgrounds, that's set through `gsettings`. In a nut shell, it's a form of database for settings to various apps. The simple command is this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$FILE"
```

, where `"$FILE"` is the shell script variable that holds full path to image in the form `file:///path/to/image.png`

That's somewhat different from other desktop environments. Think of Ubuntu's Unity   and Gnome as having a layer above typical X11 server ( i.e. the layer above GUI environment ). In such environments as `blackbox` or `openbox` you'd need to call an external program. For instance , `feh --bg-scale /path/to/image`

I assume you want to deal with default environment - Ubuntu's Unity.

**Making a shell function**

Here's example of what I use in my `.bashrc` file.

```
function chbackground {
    FILE="'file://$(readlink -f "$1" )'" 
    echo changing to "$FILE" 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$FILE" 
}
```

The function can be called like so

```
chbackground WALLPAPERS-FOLDER/cool-background.png
```

This function has two important parts. First, we can either have full path or partial path to the file - that's what `readlink -f "$1"` takes care of - it returns full path to image. Then we turn that into a string by combining output of `readlink -f "$1"` and `file://`. Remember, Unix path is always starting with root folder, `/`, so we need only leading two slashes there. Result would be `file:///home/user/WALLPAPERS-FOLDER/cool-background.png` string and stored in `FILE` variable.

Finally we call `gsettings` with `FILE` as argument.

This function can be part of any script and called with any partial or full path as parameter

**Putting together a script**

Here's a script I sketched out in about 15 minutes that will make a list of images , and then select random image out of that list, and set background to that image. The script is also placed in my [github](https://github.com/SergKolo/)  , [sergrep](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep) repository repository and will be developed just a little bit more to include extra functionality, but for the most part , the code version here does the big job.

In order to automate this script , refer to [How do i make a program autostart every time i log in ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/134369/295286)

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: March 10th 2016 
# Purpose: Set random wallpaper
#      To make it start automatically, add it as one of 
#          the Startup Applications in Ubuntu's Unity 
#          or Gnome 
# 
# Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/744464/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

ARGV0="$0"
ARGC=$#
change_background()
{
    FILE="'file://$(readlink -f "$1" )'" 
    echo changing to "$FILE" 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$FILE"
}

make_list()
{
  # -max-depth may be optional , if you want to 
  # traverse subdirectories,too
  find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f > "$2"
}

main()
{
  # Variables
  local DISPLAY=:0 # ensure this is set
  local DIR="$1"
  local LIST="/tmp/wallpaper.list"
  local TIME="$2"
  # cat $LIST # for debugging only
  make_list "$DIR" "$LIST"
  while true 
  do
     change_background $( shuf $LIST | head -n 1   )
     sleep "$TIME"      
  done
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: @fabionr Well, glad I could help. Um, keep in mind , cron runs as root and doesn't have access to GUI unless you give it `DISPLAY=:0` so that might not be the best solution. I will be adding more stuff to this answer, so check it out later :) Happy coding !

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the script but it is not working yet. I just copied the script you gave me and i'm calling it to change at each 10seconds (just to test). I'm having this output:

fabio@fabio-PC:~/Desktop$ `sudo bash chbk.bashrc /home/fabio/Pictures/wallpapers/ 10`
changing to 'file:///home/fabio/Pictures/wallpapers/Wallpaper-60E.jpg'
changing to 'file:///home/fabio/Pictures/wallpapers/HD-Wallpapers-89_rElkAPy.jpg'  etc...
It is saying that is changing the background but it stills the same...

Comment: Well, you are calling the script with `sudo` . You don't need that.  `gsettings` schemas are set per user. If you are running that as root, you are changing `gsettings` for root, but you want to change it for your account

Comment: You're welcome :)  Check out my other scripts on git. Also keep checking this answer time to time, i plan on editing it and improving