# Can I automatically change the desktop wallpaper everytime I log on

Tags: unity, scripts, desktop-background, autostart

I have learned how to change the background via the terminal but can I get the terminal to change to a different background every time I log on?

Comment: See these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity, http://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will read carefully and learn :D

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

The script below takes a directory as argument ( preferably only containing images ) , selects random item form its contents, and sets the item as wallpaper. It is intended to be started on user's login, although can be used by itself just as well.

#### Setting up and Usage

First of all, the script must be stored somewhere on the system. Preferably, it should be placed into your `~/bin` directory. If you don't have `bin` directory in your home directory, then just create one.

Next,ensure the script has executable permissions. You can use either `chmod +x ~/bin/set_random_wallpaper.py` or do it the GUI way by right clicking on the file and checking `Allow executing file as program` in the Permissions tab of the Properties menu.

The script requires a directory as argument. Preferably, you should give it full path. For example:

```
set_random_wallpaper.py /home/JohnDoe/Pictures/wallpapers/
```

If you are doing it via command-line, then you can give relative path, `Pictures/wallpapers/` , but for setting it up to run upon login automatically , use full path.

To make the file run upon every login, open Startup Applications program and click "Add" button. Use full path to command and to folder:

```
/home/JohnDoe/bin/set_random_wallpaper.py /home/JohnDoe/Pictures/wallpapers/
```

That's it !

#### Script Source

The script is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/set_random_wallpaper.py):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Author: Serg Kolo , <1047481448@qq.com>
Date: December, 21,2016
Purpose: Sets random wallpaper from a given directory
Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/851705/295286
"""
from gi.repository import Gio
import os,sys,random

def gsettings_set(schema, path, key, value):
    """Set value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema, path)
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return gsettings.set_strv(key, value)
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return gsettings.set_int(key, value)
    if isinstance(value,str): 
        return gsettings.set_string(key,value)

def error_and_exit(message):
    sys.stderr.write(message + "\n")
    sys.exit(1)

def select_random_uri(dir_path):

    selection = random.choice(os.listdir(dir_path))
    selection_path = os.path.join(dir_path,selection)
    while not os.path.isfile(selection_path):
        selection = random.choice(os.listdir(dir_path))
        selection_path = os.path.join(dir_path,selection)

    selection_uri = Gio.File.new_for_path(selection_path).get_uri()
    return selection_uri

def main():
    """ Program entry point"""
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
       error_and_exit('>>> Script requires path to a directory as single argument')
    if not os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):
       error_and_exit('>>> Argument is not a directory')   
    img_dir = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    uri = select_random_uri(img_dir)
    try:
        gsettings_set('org.gnome.desktop.background',None,'picture-uri',uri)
    except Exception as ex:
       error_and_exit(ex.repr()) 

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

#### Technical details and theory of operation

The script itself works in pretty simple way, but I spiced it up with a few functions of my own. The main function checks if there is an argument and if that argument is a directory - otherwise it quits. If everything is OK, we proceed to get absolute path of the directory, and give it to `set_random_uri()` function.

As you may or may not know, the wallpaper is set in `dconf` database, which can be accessed and altered with `gsettings` command. The simple command line way is

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/JohnDoe/Pictures/cool_wallpaper.jpg
```

The `file://...` part is the file's URI (which is essentially a encoded path of the file, and is quite useful if your system uses different locale than English). First, we need to select random file and get its URI. That's simple - we use `random.choice()` to select from list and `os.listdir()` to get list of items in directory. What if our random selection happens to be a directory and not a file ? Well, that's what while loop is for in `select_random_uri`. Once we're happy with the selection, we get its

Well, from there that is pretty much the same thing that is happening in `gsettings set` command, but I'm using custom-written `gsettings_set()` function, avoiding the need to call an external command, and it has been useful for other projects, such as [Launcher List Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/817125/295286).

That's it ! Have fun coding and enjoy Ubuntu responsibly !

#### Additional resource

- Bash version of such script has been implemented before, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/744470/295286