# Shell script runs well when triggered via terminal but not working as a cron

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I am using Ubuntu 16.06 and here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

recordmydesktop --quick-subsampling --fps 3 --no-sound --on-the-fly-encoding --v_quality 40 -o /home/square/Videos/test/rec_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`.ogv
```

when i run the script from the terminal like that `./script.sh` everything goes well and running.

However when i place an cronjob looking like that:

```
*/1   *    *    *    *  /home/square/playground/script.sh &>/home/square/playground/mylog.log
```

The command:

```
recordmydesktop --quick-subsampling --fps 3 --no-sound --on-the-fly-encoding --v_quality 40 -o /home/square/Videos/test/rec_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`.ogv
```

Is not working. I have no idea why it is running when i run the `script.sh` from the terminal, but it is not working via the cron job.

Do you have any idea how i can fix that ?

Comment: Edit `export DISPLAY=:0.0` in script.

Answer (score 0):

recordmydesktop records the X-session it is started in.

Processes started from crontab don't have an X-session.

Comment: Is there anyway i can start that with cron or with the starting of the PC ?

Comment: I really don't think so. As far as I can see, you have to start it after you have logged in.

Comment: But maybe you can use Startup Applications in your Desktop. It should be found in "Menu > Preferences > Startup Applications", see this article http://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in